# Column header is empty when using setHorizontalHeaderLabels in tableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am new to QtDesigner, i am trying to learn and code, however I am not understanding why below simple code will not set column header name in tableWidget.

according to documentation if i want to set column name it should be like this

```
ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'))
```

but when program load, it does not show the header name, Ami i missing any class or object references?

Can any one please tell me where i am doing wrong?

the full code is here, its simple

```
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'table_view.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(850, 363)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 511, 192))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 280, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'))
    ui.tableWidget.show()
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The issue is that the column count of the table is set to zero, so the column names are set but there are no columns to display. Try `self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)`. Also, it generally a bad idea to edit the python files generated by QtDesigner directly. It's better to import it in a separate python file and put all your custom code in there.

Comment: @Heike Thanks, which means if i want to set column header dynamic, do i need to change that properties dynamically or shall i not use that properties at all ?
Regards to QtDesigner directly, yes sure, i will remember that next time

Comment: @Heike, How do i comment your Solution as Answered ?

Comment: you can't mark comments as accepted answer. I've added an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the column count of the table is set to zero, so the column names are set but there are no columns to display. To set the number of columns in your table you can use `self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)`.

Also, it generally a bad idea to edit the python files generated by QtDesigner directly. It's better to import it in a separate python file and put all your custom code in there.